# Rails 4: getting Twitter share button to work with Turbolinks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter, coffeescript, turbolinks

I'm trying to get the Twitter share button to work with a Rails 4 app + Turbolinks.

In my view, I have:

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-lang="en" data-text="<%= @article.title %>" data-via="<%= t('twitter_user') %>">Tweet</a>
```

I also have a **twitter.js.coffee** file in my app/assets/javascripts/ directory:

```
class @Twitter
    eventsBound = false
    @load: ->
        Twitter.loadTwitterSDK()
        Twitter.bindEvents() unless Twitter.eventsBound
    @bindEvents: ->
        if typeof Turbolinks isnt 'undefined' and Turbolinks.supported
            $(document).on('page:load', Twitter.renderTweetButtons)
        Twitter.eventsBound = true
    @renderTweetButtons: ->
        $('.twitter-share-button').each ->
            button = $(this)
            button.attr('data-url', document.location.href) unless button.data('url')?
            button.attr('data-text', document.title) unless button.data('text')?
    @loadTwitterSDK: ->
        $.getScript("//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js")
Twitter.load()
```

The button appears when I hard refresh the page but disappears when navigating (likely due to Turbolinks). I probably need to keep calling the renderTweetButtons function, but am not sure how.

Any help appreciated! Thanks :)

Comment: Try adding data-no-turbolink="false" to the link?

Comment: That makes no difference :\

Comment: What about data-no-turbolink="true" ?

Comment: Same thing, the share on Twitter button doesn't appear until I refresh the page manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was that I was missing `twttr.widgets.load()` within @renderTweetButtons as documented [here](https://dev.twitter.com/web/javascript/initialization). This is what the complete file looks like now:

```
class @Twitter
    eventsBound = false
    @load: ->
        Twitter.loadTwitterSDK()
        Twitter.bindEvents() unless Twitter.eventsBound
    @bindEvents: ->
        if typeof Turbolinks isnt 'undefined' and Turbolinks.supported
            $(document).on('page:load', Twitter.renderTweetButtons)
        Twitter.eventsBound = true
    @renderTweetButtons: ->
        $('.twitter-share-button').each ->
            button = $(this)
            button.attr('data-url', document.location.href) unless button.data('url')?
            button.attr('data-text', document.title) unless button.data('text')?
        twttr.widgets.load()
    @loadTwitterSDK: ->
        $.getScript("//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js")
Twitter.load()
```

That solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
Twitter.load()
```

try:

```
$(document).ready(Twitter.load())
$(document).on('page:load', Twitter.load())
```

Comment: Same. Unless I hard refresh the Twitter share icon doesn't appear. I have a feeling this might have to do with Twitter's widgets.js file which is calling preventDefault in a bunch of different places.

Answer (score 0):

It's worked for me:

Replace the supplied javascript snippet with an external script tag pointing to platform.twitter.com/widgets.js.

```
<body>
  <a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-url="http://example.org" data-size="large">Tweet</a>
  <script src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script>
</body>
```

source [here](http://reed.github.io/turbolinks-compatibility/twitter.html)